# Scrape values generated by script from active tab chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to scrape values from a page that have been generated by a JS script. When I inspect the page, i see the values there, but my selectors return null/undefined.

The purpose of the extension is to allow people, on click of a button, to scrape their personalised data from a page that requires login  WITHOUT having to provide any login details to the extension.

In chrome-console, the static "title" values return, so i'm pretty sure my selectors are fine and it's just that accessing the document doesn't count for the executed scripts.

From reading, I might need to use something like pupeteer or selenium, but it seems they fire up their own browser instance (bad, as I'd need to take user login details to mock the sign in process) or i'd need to modify how the chrome browser starts with `--remote-debugging-port=A_PORT_NUMBER` which i want to avoid.

From chrome console and my extension, I can retrieve the values highlighted green, (so it is not an issue with iframes as some posts suggest) and can't retrieve values highlighted red.

HTML structure in image

[image]

From **popup.html**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
...
    document.querySelector('button[id="scrape"]').addEventListener("click", function onclick() {
        chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true },
            function (activeTab) { 
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab[0].id, { action: "putSource_scrapeSalePage", index: activeTab[0].index })
            }
        )
    })
    ...
 }, false)
```

From **content.js**

```js
//Need to import pupeteer/selenium here? How else to use it for active tab?

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) { 
    ...
      else if (request.action === "putSource_scrapeSalePage") {
          let htmlvar = $(document)
          console.log(htmlvar);
          let test = $('td[desc= "transactionType"]').text().trim() //returns fine
          
          let tableData1raw = $('table.tableDataOne tbody tr').find("tbody").find("tr")

          let tableData1raw_almost = $(tableData1raw).each(function (i, element) {
              console.log(element)
              const $element = $(element).find("td")
              console.log($element)
...
```

---

**The Question:**

**If there is no better way to do this,  how can I do this from content-script with something like pupeteer?**

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to use the Value i know i COULD get ("transaction type" title) and use it to traverse to it's sibling element (+) and retrieve whatever Div was there, instead of trying to target the Div class directly.

$('td[desc= "transactionType"] + td').find("div").text();